# closure with additional curly braces

Tags: javascript

The source of jquery starts with something like that:

```
;(function (props) {..}(props) 

// I do not understand the following curly braces:  
{...}

));
```

I am aware that this is a anonymous function expression (closure) which executes (only once) after script is loaded. Something like that ("normal closure"):

```
(function(props){
...

}(props));
```

However, I do not understand what the additional curly braces are doing (benefits, use-cases). In a "normal closure", I do not use these curly braces.

Comment: The code you posted is syntactically invalid, too many `)` (which makes me wonder whether you got the overall syntax wrong). What's the actual code? In general, `{...}` denotes a *block*, and it's very rarely used outside of `if` statements or loops, because it doesn't have any additional benefits.

Comment: The code fragment seems to be valid! Look at the source of "jQuery v2.1.0" which starts with such a fragment: "(function( global, factory ) {...}(...){..}));" I know, it s weird, but they use it. Something like a "sandwich closure":)

Comment: If you count the number of opening `(` and the number of closing `)` then you see that they are not balanced.

Comment: And it's as I expected, you're missing the most important part of the code. The jQuery source code looks like `(function( global, factory ) {...} (typeof window ..., function(...) {...}));` I.e. the function gets passed two arguments, `window` and another function. So I assume the curly braces you mean are actually part of that other function definition. If you count the parenthesis (`()`) now, they match.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I missed it. Now it is clear. Thank you!!

Comment: Also, to clear up terminology, nothing in your post is a closure. You're showing what has been coined as IIFE--Immediately Invoked Function Expressions. These are the definition of an anonymous function using literal syntax, and immediate invocation thereof. IIFE's are often used to create closures, but are not themselves closures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extra curly braces are part of a function definition, which you miss in your question. The  actual code looks more like this:

```
;(function( global, factory ) {

  // ...

} (typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window : this, function(...) {

  // ...

}));
```

I.e. the function gets passed two arguments, `window` and another function. If you count the parenthesis (`()`) now, they match.